# How to merge an external audio source with my iPhone's audio out?

Tags: audio, headphones

I would like to be able to combine an external signal (available only via headphone cable) with the the audio out of my iPhone and listen to both of them using headphones. I know this is possible with an external mixer, but I'm hoping the folks here my have a better way to do this. Maybe the phone can take audio in via the lightning connector or bluetooth and merge it? Or maybe there's a tiny purpose built mixer for this two headphone-level input use case. I care only about the music player on the iPhone, or possibly streaming music like Pandora. I don't need actual phone calls or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called Audiobus, in the Appstore you can find multiple AudioBus compatible Apps, you can choose multiple source and let them stream in compatible apps or on the headphones or other outputs available on your iPhone.

Comment: I have an external audio source with a headphone jack, how do I get that into the iPhone so audiobus can mix it and output the mixed result to the iPhone's headphone jack?

Comment: it must exist a cable but it is only mono, and counted as Microphone

Comment: here is a video I just found with explanations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFOBDx3fcYA